# Limit involving primes numbers

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, distribution-of-primes

For each integer $n$ denote by $p_{n}$ the largest prime less or equal than $n$. 
 So, $p_{2}=2$, $p_{3}=3$, $p_{4}=3$, $p_{5}=5$, $p_{6}=5$ and so on.

Then, there exists the limit $\lim_{n}\frac{p_{n}}{n}$?

Many thanks in advances for your comments.

Comment: Do you know the *prime number theorem*?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I do, but I fail to see the connection. Note that $p_n$ is *not* the $n^\text{th}$ prime.

Comment: Are you looking for a simple Yes/No answer, or do you need a *proof*?  If the latter, what can you take as known about the distribution of primes? (Bertrand's Postulate is not enough; the Prime Number Theorem is more than adequate.)

Comment: Many thanks! The lim sup is equal to 1 (is clear taking the sequence of primes).

Comment: For any $\varepsilon$ and large $n$, there is a prime between $(1-\varepsilon)n$ and $n$. This is an easy consequence of PNT, I recommend you try to prove it yourself.

Comment: For $p_j$ a subsequence of your sequence, composed of the prime numbers, the value of $p_j/j$ is constant and equals to 1. Hence either your limit is 1 or it does not exist. But indeed it does seems tricky to actually prove this limit.

Comment: May I suggest you change the notation for your sequence to $a_n$? I understood right away that your $p_n$ is not the n-th prime number, but while trying to write a response, this was really confusing to me, and would also force me to use some non-usual notation for the n-th prime.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Somme remarks:
(i) The Prime Number Theory seems not be clear to apply in this case, as $p_{n}$  is not an arbitrary prime.
(ii) $p_{n}$ is the largest prime which does not exceeds to $n$. So, $p_{2}=p_{3}=2$, $p_{4}=3$, $p_{10}=7$, $p_{11}=11$, $p_ {12}=11$,.....
(iii) If the limit of $p_{n}/n$ is equal to 1, What is the limit of   $(p_{n}/n)^{n} $??  

Many thanks!

Comment: @user123043 Regarding your comment-question (iii): The limit of $(p_n/n)^n$ does not exist. If $n$ is a prime, the expression is equal to $1$. If $n>3$ is one-more-than-a-prime, the expression is equal to $(1-1/n)^n$. The former subsequence tends to $1$, while the latter to $(1/e)$, so the full sequence does not have a limit.

Answer (score 1):

This question is closely related to the [prime gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) problem. The notation is slightly different: $p_n$ on Wikipedia is the $n^{th}$ prime while $g_n$ is the gap after that prime. I will stick to this notation, and use $a_n$ for the terms in your sequence to avoid confusion.

Wikipedia mentions that the quotient between the prime gap and the prime preceding the gap goes to 0:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g_n}{p_n}=0.$$
Later I will use the prime following each gap. It follows trivially that also $\lim_{n\to\infty} g_{n-1} / p_{n}=0.$

Back to your problem. If the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exists, it has to be 1 (since the value 1 is attained when $n$ is prime). The largest deviation between $a_n$ and 1 occurs when $n+1$ is prime. Consider the subsequence of points where the largest gaps occur, i.e., the subsequence $(a_{p_n-1})_{n=1}^\infty$. We have $a_{p_n-1} = (p_n-g_{n-1}) / (p_n-1)$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{p_n-1} = 1$. Therefore also $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 1$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, if $n_{k}$ is the sequence of primes numbers, using your notation, $a_{n_{k}}=1$ for each $k$. So, if the limit exists, it has to be equal to 1. See also the above  Mefitico comment.

Comment: @user123043 you are right, I had it as 1 at some point and then changed it into 0 due to confusion. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

I will denote the number of primes less than or equal to $n$ a $\pi(n)$, the $n$th prime as $p_n$, and the largest prime less than or equal to $n$ as $q_n=p_{\pi(n)}$.

Clearly $1 \geq \frac{q_n}{n} \geq \frac{p_{\pi(n)}}{p_{\pi(n)+1}}$. Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{p_n}{p_{n+1}}=1$, we have that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{q_n}{n}=1$ by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Many thanks Jacob. Your answer seems to be correct.